# Why Angular evaluates first route only?

Tags: angular

I have the following routes which all have the same path. The route is activated based on logic in the `canLoad` but Angular evaluates the first route with data `A` only and does not go through second if the first fails. I tested the logic in the `canLoad` and there is nothing wrong there. It returns true and false.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canLoad: [AuthGuardProviderService],
        data: {provider: 'A'},
        loadChildren: () => import('./xx/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        canLoad: [AuthGuardProviderService],
        loadChildren: () => import('./x/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

CanLoad:

```
export class AuthGuardProviderService implements CanLoad {

  constructor() {
  }

  canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
    const data = route.data.provider;
    return this.getRoute(data);
  }

  private getRoute(data): boolean {
    const paths = location.href.split('/');
    if (data === 'A') {
      return true;
    } else if (!data) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated question using `UrlMatcher`:**

> what you're trying to accomplish with this implementation

User case: I have multiple modules and load a module based on URL. For instance:
User A hits: `localhost/a` and the module loads.

```
path: '',
loadChildren: () => import('./a/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
```

And if User B hits: `localhost/b` I want to load:

```
path: '',
loadChildren: () => import('./b/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
```

I can use `UrlMatcher` but this works only for first route.

```
const matcher = (url: UrlSegment[], providerParam) => {
  const paths = location.href.split('/');
  if ((paths[3] === '' || paths[3] === 'auth') && providerParam === 'win') {
    return {consumed: url};
  } else if (paths[3] !== '') {
    const provider = providers.find(p => paths[3].toLowerCase() === p.shortName);
    return provider && provider.shortName === providerParam ? {consumed: url} : null;
  }
  return null;
};
```

And the lazy load module has:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'sign-in',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'sign-up',
        component: NbRegisterComponent,
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

Now the problem with this approach is that it always loads `sign-in` component. It always hits `path: ''` not going to other paths like `auth/sign-up`

It might be worth to mention that if user hits `localhost/a` I am setting `a` as `baseHref`, therefore, I cannot use this as a path. It would be straight forward if I don't set it as `baseHref`. The `a` or `b` path is not part of the route.

> It would also help provide more context if we could see your guard
>   implementation

I also tried using `guard` but that is not helpful either since all paths are same `''` empty string, and Angular routes matches the first one and does not evaluate guard on the rest.

> what data you want to associate with the first route and how you're
>   planning to use it

The purpose of the data is just to know which route is being evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With issues like this, I always find it helpful to enable route tracing so I can see what the Angular router is doing by watching browser console. More information can never hurt.

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only!!!
    )
]
```

The Angular Router iterates over the `routes` array comparing the `window.location.href` value with the `path` variable for each of your routes. Once it finds a match, it loads the component or module associated with that path. As you've seen, it does not continue iterating over the `routes` array looking for other possible matches. If it did, the Angular Router would then have to determine what route configuration wins, which would likely be too implementation-specific to handle in a generic way at the framework level.

Thankfully, the Angular team does provide an API called the [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) that allows the developer to make that decision. That's an option if you cannot change the route setup for some reason.

In my opinion, we should always avoid changing the default behavior of a framework if at all possible. At a high level, I would recommend using two different route paths and implementing logic in your guard to check for data `A`. If it exists and it is what your app expects, load the module in the first route; otherwise, redirect to the second route.

We could provide a more specific solution if we knew:

- what data you want to associate with the first route and how you're planning to use it
- what you're trying to accomplish with this implementation (Something
  like: when a user navigates to my app, I want to check to see if
  they're authenticated. If they are, they proceed with the first
  route; otherwise, they are redirected to the second route to kick off
  the authentication process)
- It would also help provide more context if we could see your guard implementation

If you don't find any of this helpful so far and you're unable to provide more information, try taking a look at this post => [The Three Pillars of the Angular Router — Router States and URL Matching](https://indepth.dev/the-three-pillars-of-the-angular-router-router-states-and-url-matching/). It goes more into depth about how the router works and how it handles things like Url segments.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation. I updated the question with more details and my attempt with `UrlMatcher`

Comment: I saw that the problem you see with the UrlMatcher approach is that Url Segments are not preserved. What Url Segements do you need to preserve?

Comment: from `auth/sign-up`, I want to preserve `sign-up` so the user sees sign-up component.

Answer (score 0):

Angular only matches on the first. It won't proceed even if your guard fails. You can look into something called a matcher which can replace the path argument as one way around this.

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher